# Python: convert Chinese characters into pinyin with CJKLIB

Tags: python, unicode, cjk

I'm trying to convert a bunch of Chinese characters into pinyin, reading the characters from one file and writing the pinyin into another. I'm working with the CJKLIB functions to do this.

Here's the code,

```
from cjklib.characterlookup import CharacterLookup

source_file = 'cities_test.txt'
dest_file = 'output.txt'

s = open(source_file, 'r')
d = open(dest_file, 'w')

cjk = CharacterLookup('T')

for line in s:
    p = line.split('\t')
    for p_shard in p:
        for c in p_shard:
            readings = cjk.getReadingForCharacter(c.encode('utf-8'), 'Pinyin')
            d.write(readings[0].encode('utf-8'))
        d.write('\t')
    d.write('\n')

s.close()
d.close()
```

My problem is that I keep running into Unicode-related errors, the error comes up when I call the `getReadingForCharacter` function. If I called it as written,

```
readings = cjk.getReadingForCharacter(c.encode('utf-8'), 'Pinyin')
```

I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range (128).

If I call it like this, without the `.encoding()`,

```
readings = cjk.getReadingForCharacter(c, 'Pinyin')
```

I get an error thrown by sqlalchemy (the CJKLIB uses sqlalchemy and sqlite): You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings ... etc.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Oh also, is there a way for CJKLIB to return the pinyin without any tones? I think by default it's returning pinyin with these weird characters to represent tones, I just want the letters without these tones.

Comment: Does it just regular Unicode strings, not encoded stuff?  That would be the cleaner interface.

Comment: What does that mean? I'm still a novice.

Comment: You aren’t decoding your input; indeed, you’re double-encoding it.  Set the input stream encoding to utf-8 and then just pass a Unicode string to the function.  Test it by passing some `\uXXXX` CJK code point, like `u"\u6771"` (in oldschool Python 2 if you haven’t imported `unicode_literals` from `__future__`; skip the ugly  `u""` prefix in modern Python and just use `"\u6771"` or `chr(0x6771)`) to mean `東`, the first kanji in Tokyo. If it behaves right with that, you know you should be using Unicode strings.

Comment: Not sure if I understand how to do any of that. 1) how do I set the input stream to utf-8? Is it something like codecs.open('file', encoding='utf-8', mode='w') or something? 2) how to I pass a Unicode string to the function? Does everything that comes out of the utf-8 encoded stream automatically become unicode?

Comment: Make a small test that simply calls `cjk.getReadingForCharacter(unichr(0x6771),'Pinyin')` in Python 2 or `cjk.getReadingForCharacter(chr(0x6771, 'Pinyin')` in Python 3. CJK `東京` is `dōng jīng` in Pinyin, and the first of those code points is U+6771, so you should get something like `dong` back if you pass it a Unicode string with that code point in it. If that works, then your bug is calling `encode` instead of `decode`, which is my suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is that you are not decoding the input stream, and yet you are turning around and *re-encoding* it as though it were UTF-8.    That’s going the wrong way.

You have two choices.

You can `codecs.open` the input file with an explicit encoding so you always get back regular Unicode strings whenever you read from it because the decoding is automatic. This is always my strong preference. There is no such thing as a text file anymore.

Your other choice is to manually decode your binary string it before you pass it to the function. I hate this style, because it almost always indicates that you're doing something wrong, and even when it doesn't, it is clumsy as all get out.

I would do the same thing for the output file.  I just hate seeing manually `.encode("utf-8")` and `.decode("utf-8")` all over the place.  Set the stream encoding and be done with it.